# How to Split string into multiple values using best approach

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005

We are trying to save result of a query in database by tokenizing a column but query is taking more than 3 minutes to finish his objective. My question is, do we have any faster way to tokenize a column?

Query:

```
Select *
from
(
        SELECT TblTwo.ID Desc_ID,
           (CASE WHEN TblTwo.Description_Type = 'Default' THEN coalesce(tblOne.Code + ' ','') ELSE '' END) + TblTwo.[Description] AS String   
        FROM TableOne tblOne
        INNER JOIN TableTwo TblTwo ON tblOne.CodeID = TblTwo.CodeID
        WHERE TblTwo.Description_Type IN ('Default','Custom')
)ResultOne   ---- Return almost 20000 rows and take 1 sec to execute 
CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_TokenString(String) ---- return almost 194379 rows and take 3 mins to execute
```

Result of drived table ResultOne :
Desc_ID     String
1           HCD.39877
2           HCD.39777 Personal test history of documents
4           CD.397 Unspecified document text
5           N.7 This is end of file

Script of function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].udf_TokenString (@string VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS
@Results TABLE
(
    Item VARCHAR(255),
    location INT,
    Sequence INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
)
AS
BEGIN


    DECLARE @Len INT, @Start INT, @end INT, @Cursor INT,@length INT

    SELECT @Cursor=1, @len=LEN(@string)

    WHILE @cursor<@len
       BEGIN

       SELECT @start=PATINDEX('%[^.A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9%]%',
                       ' '+SUBSTRING (@string,@cursor,50)
                       )-1

       IF @start<0 break               

       SELECT @length=PATINDEX('%[^.A-Z''a-z0-9-%]%',SUBSTRING (@string,@cursor+@start+1,50)+' ')  
       INSERT INTO @results(item, location)
           SELECT  SUBSTRING(@string,@cursor+@start,@length), @cursor+@start
       SELECT @Cursor=@Cursor+@Start+@length+1

       END
    RETURN

END


GO
```

Comment: Yeah, that is about the slowest way to split strings. See http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings or, better yet, stop storing these awful comma-separated strings in the first place : http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql

Comment: @AaronBertrand actually source is a table which we get from a third party which contain code and their descriptions. What we do is we store those descriptions after splitting and its per day as many times as client wants activity, therefore i need a better solution

Comment: If you have to split the string then the absolute fastest way would be to use a CLR and reference a .NET library to do it.  SQL is just going to suck at string manipulation.  Or use the import process (SSIS?, other?) to properly normalize the data prior to putting it in your database.

Comment: @AA.SC Why are you using `PATINDEX('%[^.A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9%]%',` ? Do you have multiple delimiters? Do you really have a variable number of these 1 or more delimiters in a row? Meaning, is your incoming data, if splitting on a space, sometimes separated by 3 spaces or 5 or a `?` or a `^`? I can't see any other purpose in using that `PATINDEX` construct unless this is the case.